# Which internet i use when i use VPN in windows

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-sbs

I use my VPN to my company so that i can use remote desktop. I stay connected all night.

I just want to know that while my VPN is active and i download stuff from internet does i download from my company internet or my LAN

Comment: When you are connected to the VPN all traffic goes through the VPN and back to your internet.  This is how you are able to connect to your desktop at work, because you are actually connected to your work's network, if you want to browse the internet disconnect from the VPN

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you are using IPsec, then your VPN client can decide what to do with outgoing (and incoming) packets based on the source/destination IP address and port number.

It could either 1) let packets bypass the VPN, 2) tunnel them to your company's LAN or 3) block them altogether.

I think you need to provide more details before you get a straight answer, but I'd say there's a fair chance your activity could be monitored and you might want to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention of question is regarding data usage:

1. The stuff you download is through your VPN or let's say you company
   network. Data is charged for the services.
2. Even if you connect through VPN and download, data is being charged for the internet                connection that you are using to connect to VPN.